# Having problems with Google Places API

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I have a Fragment called "MainScreen", after I press a button in this Fragment I want to show the user the PlacePicker and after he chooses a place to return him to a different *Activity* called BusinessView and not back to the "MainScreen" Fragment. The problem is that the app crashes when it tries to build the new activity in builder.build(b), I looked at the logcat and it's giving me this error: *"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference"*

This is the code:

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
builder.setLatLngBounds(bounds);
try {
    BusinessView b = new BusinessView();
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(b), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
}
catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "For some reason"...  Did you read the logcat? Can you add it to the question, please?

Comment: Please send ur logcat

Comment: I think this might be the reason "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference"